# how to convert a sequential data seperated by | and does not have newline character into rows and columns in pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, replace, bigdata, regexp-replace

I'm trying to read the text file which has sequential data separated by | as below.

```
1|Ariyalur|1|2|3|2|Coimbatore|4|6|1.12|3|Cuddalore|8|3|7
```

I want the spark to read it as dataframe and replace the 5th delimiter (i.e |) with \n.
the output should be

```
Serial_Number|District|Area|Production|profit
1|Ariyalur|1|2|3
2|Coimbatore|4|6|1.12
3|Cuddalore|8|3|7
```

Using replace function replaces all the |. how to replace only the 5th instance of |.

Answer (score 1):

After trying few different approaches, I figure applying regex pattern is the best way to split, it's a bit tricky but it works

```py
split_token = '~' # this is the token to split, you can decide what's the best token depends on your data

(df
    .withColumn('tmp', F.regexp_replace(F.col('seq'), '(([^\|]+)\|){4}[^\|]+', f'$0{split_token}')) # Add split token         =====>   1|Ariyalur|1|2|3~|2|Coimbatore|4|6|1.12~|3|Cuddalore|8|3|7~
    .withColumn('tmp', F.explode(F.split(F.col('tmp'), f'{split_token}\|?')))                       # Explode by split token  =====>   [ 1|Ariyalur|1|2|3, 2|Coimbatore|4|6|1.12, 3|Cuddalore|8|3|7, ]
    .withColumn('tmp', F.split(F.col('tmp'), '\|'))                                                 # Split by pipe (|)       =====>   [ 1, Ariyalur, 1, 2, 3 ]
    .withColumn('serial_number', F.col('tmp')[0]) # extract `serial_number`
    .withColumn('district', F.col('tmp')[1])      # extract `district`
    .withColumn('area', F.col('tmp')[2])          # extract `area`
    .withColumn('production', F.col('tmp')[3])    # extract `production`
    .withColumn('profit', F.col('tmp')[4])        # extract `profit`
    .drop('seq', 'tmp')                           # clean up
    .where(F.col('profit').isNotNull())           # clean up
    .show(10, False)
)

# +-------------+----------+----+----------+------+
# |serial_number|district  |area|production|profit|
# +-------------+----------+----+----------+------+
# |1            |Ariyalur  |1   |2         |3     |
# |2            |Coimbatore|4   |6         |1.12  |
# |3            |Cuddalore |8   |3         |7     |
# +-------------+----------+----+----------+------+
```